# Need to identify this pin / terminal

Tags: pins, terminal, wire-terminals

I need to identify this pin so I can order more.

**RESEARCH:** I've pored over Molex.com, Allied Electronics, and here with no success. I also reached out to JST and Allied directly but they were unable to identify it.

**SOURCE:** These are found inside an aftermarket automotive headlight produced in 2000 by an obscure company that stopped making them years ago. I tried contacting the OEM and various parts stores to no avail. Other components in the vicinity of these pins/terminals were made by JST, hence why I contacted JST directly.

**ITEM IN QUESTION:** It really looks like two pins mated together, but it's one piece. It's secured by opposing winglets which are depressed by the removal tool.

Additional photos include the pin and measurements plus some online sources I've found selling the plug + pins. Shipping on these would take far longer than I am able to wait, plus these aftermarket headlights are wired differently than stock, so those pre-wired ones are definitely out.

Additional photos here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOC9G.jpg

Last time you all were able to do the impossible. Thank you in advance for your help this time around.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you embed the image into your post? Make it easy for your readers.

Comment: You have posted a lot of images on imgur. I would recommend you to add at least 2-3 most relevant images to your post.

Comment: I just added a few.

Comment: Still very much looking for these!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pins that you are looking for seems to have been made by a company know as *StarConnect*.

These have part no. :- D139 ST613-3X0. 6A/B

[Link](http://www.starconnect.com.cn/) to the company's website.

A seller at AliExpress has listed a lot of StarConnect pins in the description. [Link](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/wholesale-electrical-Auto-male-female-7_60061507718.html) to it.

[image]

Comment: Are those photos stretched? That doesn't look quite correct, though it's close. The blade looks too wide.

Comment: @Hearth, editing the image and the part no. Found a better pin option.

Comment: It looks like that pin would sit flat. That is to say, the extruded pin part at the end is flat with the bottom of the square part (sorry my wording isn't very technical). It's also missing the locking tabs. Thanks for that though, I now know these connectors are made by a company called FEP ([here](http://www.fepz.de/pdf_s_produktkatalog.pdf)) and that will certainly help narrow it down.

Comment: If we could find a part number for [these](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/2-pins-auto-electrical-connector-1928404226_60743216579.html?spm=a2700.details.maylikehoz.3.674c13aeb9fsde) pins we'd be set.

Comment: @JustinDake, Try to contact the seller on AliExpress for more info on them or just contact the manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research based on the part number in that AliExpress posting in another answer, I finally located [the correct terminals](https://store.chiefenterprises.com/1-962915-1JPT-Blade-Terminal-Tin)!

This seller identifies them as "Tyco Junior Timer blade terminals. Tyco JT terminals are specified for Bosch Compact Clutch connectors." I can also find them elsewhere by that name.

Thanks to everyone's help I can now get this car back on the road!